# custom ringtones for all contacts

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, ringtone

i tried to set custom ringtone via Es File Explorer But Still the default mobile ringtone  , it success when i set custom specific contact , the problem : i want to set custom ringtone for all contacts at one  time , android 4.2.2